# Using angular to print out all the ids in an array one at a time along with a next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using Angular to repeat all these ids in an array but limit it to showing one at time like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="id in ids | limitTo:1">
    {{array.id}}
</div>
```

I then want to have a div that when clicked will show the next id in the array, so basically increases the $index by one. Maybe something like...

```
<div ng-repeat="id in ids | limitTo:1">
    {{array.id}}<br />
    <div ng-click="$index + 1"></div>
</div>
```

The code above doesn't work so I can only surmise that I am going about this the wrong way. What's the right way to do this in Angular?

Comment: Throw it in a fiddle? Not sure where $index is coming from or it's contents?

Also you typo'd the closing </div> on your button.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the typo, the $index is just angular's term for whatever the index of the current repeat is. So in this case the $index is equal to 0 because it's just showing the first index of the array.

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is that if you're copy and pasting your code, and there was a typo in your </div> tag there might be typos other places that might be causing issues.

Comment: No, it's not a copy and paste, this is just some basic code I worked up. It's just an ng-repeat with a limit of 1. I figured I could do that and just increment the index, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can do math on the $index, but it doesn't change the array that the ng-repeat is looping over. You can create a function that will append the array. But I'm still not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @Sharondio I was trying to do what xbonez answered with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to show a single element at a time, there's no need to use an `ng-repeat`. You can just do something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.index = 0;
$scope.arr = ['your', 'array'];

$scope.increment = function() { 
  $scope.index = ($scope.index + 1) % $scope.arr.length;
};
```

And then in your view:

```
<div>
    {{arr[$index].id}}<br />
    <div ng-click="increment()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thaaaat...makes perfect sense. I'm dumb. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think we cannot do that by increment $index as limitTo 1 says index is always zero

```
<button ng-click="onClick()">click here</button>
```

and onClick

```
$scope.onClick = function(){
    //$index + 1
    $scope.ids.shift();
  }
```

Here is the plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/A1VrbUoIPLhuA78CF4DM?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qdoan/ADukg/4975/)**

You only need to use `ng-click` and `ng-init` if you want to go through your ID array one by one:

In your view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <button ng-click="index = index + 1" ng-init="index=0">
       Next ID
    </button>
    ID: {{ids[index]}}
</div>
```

In your script file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ids = [11, 21, 31, 41, 51]; //test array
}
```

Edit: you should also either disable the button when index >= arrayLength or reset the value of index to 0.